# hudson.FilePath is missing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Any suggestions would be greatly apricated. I am using Jenkins 2.263.3 and the Jenkins server is running on a Windows box. I keep getting this error on the console when attempting any interaction with the file system. I am beginning to wonder if something is incorrect with our installation. I have looked over many of the threads and issues on stack exchange and I have not been able to figure out what is wrong. I have tried many many examples and permutations of the script below. I have stripped out everything down to the simplest I can. pwd() always throws out the same error. in fact any interaction that attempts to access the file system generates the error as follows:

```
    import hudson.*;
    
    pipeline { 
        agent {
            node {
                label 'master'
            }
        } 
    
        options {
            skipStagesAfterUnstable();
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') { 
                steps { 
                    node('master') {
                       echo "${pwd()}";
    
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Test'){
                steps {
                    echo 'test';
                }
            }
            stage('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    echo 'deploy';
                }
            }
        }
    }



The output is always the same as follows:

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bm@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] pwd
Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
Stage 'Test' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
Stage 'Deploy' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class 
 hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
    at 
 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:266)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:206)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1138)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:19)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:17)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
REST API
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've meant

```
        stages {
            stage('Build') { 
                steps { 
                    script { // and not node(){..}
                       echo "${pwd()}"
```

Comment: I get the same exception with the changes you suggest. A few things of note. The server was updated from a previous version of Jenkins by replacing the war file. The server also doesn't have access to make requests outside our network so the plugins that were required were installed manually by downloading them. This resulted in a some unsatisfied dependencies which had to each be resolved. After a bunch of downloads and reboots everything seemed to be satisfied and the server doesn't show anything as being wrong.